# How to access an event object property in javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I am using ionic push notification service.

When the app received the push, it would trigger an onNotification event with a
event object.

I had console.log the "notification" object,

but How can I access
the `raw->additionalData->foreground.`

[image]

I had tried by using `notification.raw.additionalData.forground`,

however the `notification.raw` is undefined.
Could some one give me some hint? Thanks.

```
var push = new Ionic.Push({
      "debug": true,
      "onNotification": function (notification) {
        var payload = notification.payload;
        //console.log(notification.raw.additionalData.foreground)
        // not work!! 
      }
    });
```

Comment: That little blue `i` indicates that the object was re-evaluated after logging when you expanded the properties for viewing.  Chances are you're trying to access `raw.additionalData.foreground` before it's populated.